# Cannot get css media queries to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, tablet

I have a script that appends html banners onto a page. These banners are using unique IDs that fire lightboxes on click. These lightboxes have display problems on tablets, so the solution that I'd like is to have them open as a separate page on tablets and other mobile devices.

The script is functional, and is written to determine the "position" property of a hidden element on page. If the position is "absolute" then it will append slightly different banner code than normal.

I'd like to have a media query detect tablets/mobile devices, and if so, set the position property of my hidden element to "absolute"; that way it will append the necessary code.

My media query looks like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

td > #mobileComfortDepth { position: absolute; }
}
```

This does not seem to work for me though. Am I doing this wrong? or is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Thank you in advance!

Edited Query:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

td > #mobileComfortDepth { position: absolute; }
}
```

Comment: You have two `max-device-width` instances, you have to correct one with `min-device-width`.

Comment: I'm guessing you only need the rule for `1024px`, anything lower than that you can consider mobile. Also is your problem related to the lack of horizontal space for displaying the modal content, or the problems are with the mobile devices themselves? Because some tables do have resolutions greater than `1024px` in landscape mode and this would not cover those cases.

Comment: @Bogdan The issue lies in the content of these particular modal windows. They werent really designed to be mobile friendly. Android devices allow the user to scroll the content within the modal window vertically and horisontally, however, ios devices do not. On ios, once the modal window is open, scrolling becomes limited to the page behind the lightbox.

I want all mobile behavior to be as consistent as possible, so I figured that opening them as separate pages vs modal iframes was the best route.

Comment: Then the rule `@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1024px)` should suffice. Is the rule no being applied to the element when the size width is less than `1024px`?

Comment: @Bogdan No, it isn't. I've got a nexus 7 hooked up via usb and using the remote dev tools to inspect the markup. The only time I've gotten it to do anything was when I tried setting position to "absolute !important" in the query. That did work, however, it also applied the style on the desktop as well.

Comment: If it worked with `!important` then you most likely have some specificity issue in your css and the rule in your media query gets overriden by another selector in your css. Check the css rules for that element in developer tools while testing on your tablet, I'm betting the rule from your media query is show with a strikethrough.

Comment: I cleaned up the query to reflect what I have edited above. It was still being troublesome. For whatever reason, it works just fine in production but not at all in staging (which was where I had been previously testing it). Everything is working properly now.